# Can't save double precision[] in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am quite new to PostgreSQL and pgadmin. I have created a table named "indication" with one double precision [] column. Whenever I attempt to save any double precision array data (typed here as "{23.2, 25.1}", pgadmin gives me the following error:

**ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision[] = text[] LINE 3: "Size" = ARRAY['23.2','25.1'] HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**

I'm not sure what to do here. I can use command line PSQL if necessary, but I prefer to add data via GUI.

Here's a screenshot of my error:

[image]

Comment: Entering those into the column didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating using syntax like `{23.2, 25.1}`